# Re-do an object with iterative for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, error-handling, iteration

I have a for loop like so:

```
for (Environment environment : environmentList) {
//do stuff
}
```

I catch exceptions within the loop, but would like to retry executing the code with objects that receive exceptions. Obviously I can do this with a for loop using a counter and list index, but I was curious if there was any way to do this.

Elaboration,

```
for (Environment environment : environmentList) {
try{
//do stuff
}catch(exception)
{} //retry code using current environment
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use another loop, in your for loop:

```
for (Environment environment : environmentList) {
    while (true) {
        try{

        }catch(exception) {
           continue;  // Exception: continue while
        }
        break;  // No exception: break while.
    }
}
```

But the actual behaviour will depend upon what you are doing inside the `try` block. Like, if you change the `environment` variable, then you might not get the original `environment` again. In that case, an option would be to use a block scoped copy of `environment` in your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively. You will have to code this yourself.

Bear in mind that this is fraught with difficulties. What happens if your retryable block always fails ? Do you want to loop repeatedly ? What happens if it's done *half* of what it's done before ? Do you want it to redo that again ? This retry mechanism is relatively easy to perform, but there are a lot of consequences to think about.

Some pseudo-code for a retryable component. You can abstract this out into (say) a `RetryingExecutor` and provide a `Callable`/`Runnable` to actually execute your code.

```
while (count < max) {
   try {
     return execution();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      count++;
   }

}
throw new Exception("Failed after " + count + " attempts");
```

Comment: Thanks for editing your post to include those concerns, they are very important to consider. However, I know that the block will not always fail. I am utilizing a service for queries and hitting it pretty hard, these exceptions are the occasional result. I also have no time restrictions, however important to consider. Good post, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you catch an exception, why not add the current (failed) enviroment to a list, which would build up if you had many failures. You could then attempt all the failed entries again?

You would have to be careful if you do a recursive call, as would probably end up going for ever. You could then put some constraints on that method...

Perhaps something like this....

```
yourMethod(Enviroment[] enviromentList, int attempt)
{
        switch(attempt)
        {

        case FIRST_ATTEMPT:
             for(Enviroment enviroment : enviromentList)
             {
                 try{
                      //YOUR CODE
                      }catch (Exception e){
                      failedList.add(enviroment);
                     }
              }
              yourMethod(failedList, SECOND_ATTEMPT);///RECURSIVE CALL BUT PASS IN CONSTRAINT

        case SECOND_ATTEMPT:
            //YOUR STUFF AGAIN
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I can implement such constraints using a nested while loop as @RohitJain  suggested. Great answer though, I will consider adding the failures to a list for black box testing. Thanks.